# Lazy highcharts and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using the Lazy HighCharts gem in my rails application and I have an array set up for my categories on my xAxis. I want to show just the first and last array, having the first appear on the left hand side and the last appear on the far right. Is this possible?

```
dates = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
@graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.xAxis(:categories => dates)
      f.series(:type => 'spline', :name => 'Average', :data => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], :color => '#b20838', marker: {enabled: false})
      f.legend({:align => 'right', :y => 10, :verticalAlign => 'top', :floating => "true", :borderWidth => 0})
    end
```

So instead of showing all dates on x-axis :

[image]

I would like the first and last array to show.

[image]

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, do you have any image kind of thing visualizing your requirement

Comment: Hi Strikers, I have added some images to help explain what i am after. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `:tickPositions => [0, lengthOfCategories-1]` for xAxis.

Comment: This is close. The 0 finds the first array, but the lengthOfCategories-1 doesn't work as it's looking for the variable. I tried last = dates.pop then :tickPositions => [0, last], but to no avail.

Comment: By `lengthOfCategories` I mean you need to get width of that array, not variable. There should be something like: `dates.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find out the first and last values of the labels and store them in variables before itself, then you can do some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/E7GBd/ using

```
formatter: function(){}
```

Hope this will help you.